# Why using two variable causes my query to return with no row

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have the following asp.net page which has a button for each row that the repeater creates:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptContent" OnItemCommand="btnGeneratePDF_Click">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table border="0" style="width: 95%;">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 25%;">Name</td>
                <td style="width: 25%;">Last Four SSN #</td>
                <td style="width: 25%;">PDF Generator</td>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%# Eval("name").ToString() %></td>
                <td><%# Eval("ssn3").ToString() %></td>
                <td><asp:Button ID="btnGeneratePDF" runat="server" Text="Generate PDF" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("name").ToString() + ", " + Eval("ssn3").ToString() %>' /></td>
            </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

My code behind looks like this:

```
protected void btnGeneratePDF_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] ar = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(',');
        this.writeData(ar[0], ar[1]);
    }
public void writeData(string k, string c)
    {
        Conn = new SqlConnection(cString);
        Conn.Open();

        //MessageBox.Show(k);
        //MessageBox.Show(c);

        nameE = txtName.Text;

        var pdfPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/PDFTemplates/fw9.pdf"));

        // Get the form fields for this PDF and fill them in!
        var formFieldMap = PDFHelper.GetFormFieldNames(pdfPath);
        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_01_0_[0]"] = k;

        //sqlCode = "SELECT * FROM [db].[dbo].[TablePDFTest] WHERE [name] = '" + nameE + "'";
        sqlCode = "SELECT * FROM [db].[dbo].[TablePDFTest] WHERE [name] = '" + k + "' AND [ssn3] = '" + c + "'";
        //MessageBox.Show("" + sqlCode.ToString());

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlCode, Conn))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            using (reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_02_0_[0]"] = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_04_0_[0]"] = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
                        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_05_0_[0]"] = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
                        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_07_0_[0]"] = reader.GetValue(4).ToString();
                        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].social[0].TextField1[0]"] = reader.GetValue(5).ToString();
                        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].social[0].TextField2[0]"] = reader.GetValue(6).ToString();
                        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].social[0].TextField2[1]"] = reader.GetValue(7).ToString();
                        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].social[0].TextField2[2]"] = reader.GetValue(8).ToString();
                        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].social[0].TextField2[3]"] = reader.GetValue(9).ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Requester's name and address (hard-coded)
        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_06_0_[0]"] = "Medical Group\n27 West Ave\nPurchase, NY 10577";

        var pdfContents = PDFHelper.GeneratePDF(pdfPath, formFieldMap);

        PDFHelper.ReturnPDF(pdfContents, "Completed-W9.pdf");
    }
```

If my

`sqlCode` is `sqlCode = "SELECT * FROM [DSPCONTENT01].[dbo].[TablePDFTest] WHERE [name] = '" + k + "'"; //AND [ssn3] = '" + c + "'";` it works fine for the `formFieldMap`

but if my

`sqlCode` is `sqlCode = "SELECT * FROM [DSPCONTENT01].[dbo].[TablePDFTest] WHERE [name] = '" + k + "' AND [ssn3] = '" + c + "'";` the `formFieldMap` doesn't work correctly.

This is an example of what the repeater displays:

[image]

How can I fix it?

**UPDATE**:

I did a test with `MessageBox` to display the value using the query with both variable:

```
public void writeData(string k, string c)
    {
        Conn = new SqlConnection(cString);
        Conn.Open();

        //MessageBox.Show(k);
        //MessageBox.Show(c);

        nameE = txtName.Text;

        var pdfPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/PDFTemplates/fw9.pdf"));

        // Get the form fields for this PDF and fill them in!
        var formFieldMap = PDFHelper.GetFormFieldNames(pdfPath);
        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_01_0_[0]"] = k;

        sqlCode = "SELECT * FROM [db].[dbo].[TablePDFTest] WHERE [name] = '" + k + "' AND [ssn3] = '" + c + "'";
        //MessageBox.Show("" + sqlCode.ToString());

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlCode, Conn))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            using (reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(reader.GetValue(1).ToString());
                        MessageBox.Show(reader.GetValue(2).ToString());
                        MessageBox.Show(reader.GetValue(3).ToString());
                        MessageBox.Show(reader.GetValue(4).ToString());
                        MessageBox.Show(reader.GetValue(5).ToString());
                        MessageBox.Show(reader.GetValue(6).ToString());
                        MessageBox.Show(reader.GetValue(7).ToString());
                        MessageBox.Show(reader.GetValue(8).ToString());
                        MessageBox.Show(reader.GetValue(9).ToString());
                        /*formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_02_0_[0]"] = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_04_0_[0]"] = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
                        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_05_0_[0]"] = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
                        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_07_0_[0]"] = reader.GetValue(4).ToString();
                        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].social[0].TextField1[0]"] = reader.GetValue(5).ToString();
                        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].social[0].TextField2[0]"] = reader.GetValue(6).ToString();
                        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].social[0].TextField2[1]"] = reader.GetValue(7).ToString();
                        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].social[0].TextField2[2]"] = reader.GetValue(8).ToString();
                        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].social[0].TextField2[3]"] = reader.GetValue(9).ToString();*/
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Requester's name and address (hard-coded)
        /*formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_06_0_[0]"] = "Medical Group\n27 West Ave\nPurchase, NY 10577";

        var pdfContents = PDFHelper.GeneratePDF(pdfPath, formFieldMap);

        PDFHelper.ReturnPDF(pdfContents, "Completed-W9.pdf");*/
    }
```

The messagebox isn't displayed anymore instead when I click on the button, nothing happens.

Comment: SQL injection anyone?  Use parameterized queries.

Comment: That is my next step once I get the query working correctly :) It is still in development so I am not worried at the moment. Thank you for pointing out though.

Comment: Can you define "the formFieldMap" doesn't work correctly?  Are you getting an error?  Are you not getting any results returned?  Secondly, if you call this method and set a breakpoint on "sqlCode", and perform a quickwatch on the string, what is the value?

Comment: I would argue that testing code you mean not to use is a good way to ensure you fix more bugs than is necessary.  Code it right the first time and save yourself headaches.

Comment: The question is a bit difficult to follow, but I would recond it's bacuse of the AND, there is probably no record matching both variables

Comment: @3dd When I run the query in SQL: `SELECT * FROM [db].[dbo].[TablePDFTest]
  WHERE [name] = 'john'
  AND [ssn3] = '5645'` for example, I get a row with data.

Comment: the `formFieldMap` is an iTextSharp command where I can pre-fill PDF file with data retrieved from a query. I used a messagebox to display the sqlcode in a string and it shows up exactly as when I run the query in SQL but nothing is being shown in the PDF file.

Comment: So both queries return the exact same result?

Comment: Yes only with the first query where the second argument is commented out but when I add the second argument, clicking either button returns no result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the data type of `ssn3` in SQL?  You are passing `c` as a string literal.  That is something to look at.  Maybe just try removing the single quotes around your value for c (if it is integer for instance).

Also, what happens when you type the query into a query analyzer with some test data for the WHERE clause?  Do you know if there SHOULD be rows matching both values?

Comment: It's `varchar`. I updated my code to do a test with Messagebox. What is happening is when I click either button nothing happens. I am thinking my query is screwing up somehow?

Comment: correction, you are right. I removed the `''` around the `c` and it worked. Wonder why, because it is not type `int` in the table.

Comment: My guess is there is a mess of implicit type conversion going on.  That mess would be sorted out better if you used a parameterized query, which is pretty much required for security.  You are opening yourself to a SQL injection attack with this code.  At the very least you should make sure the application identity has data reader only access to the database or you could find your DB trashed or modified to spew malicious script back to your website.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. I was able to convert one of the query which uses only one variable but wasn't sure how to use parameters with multiple variables in this case.

Comment: No problem.  If you are having trouble using parameters, do a little research, take your best shot at it, and if you have trouble just post your code in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use some ORM system, that will make your database life easier. It will also help you to avoid some sql-injections, that you've already made in your code.

Try to google Fluent NHibernate

Comment: Might be good advice, but it not an answer to the question in any way.