# How to use multiple parameters in a SQL queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I recently came across a statement on how to prevent SQL injection, so I changed my code to this (commented out are the old codes):

```
nameE = txtName.Text;

//sqlCode = "SELECT * FROM [db].[dbo].[TablePDFTest] WHERE [name] = '" + nameE + "'";
sqlCode = "SELECT * FROM [db].[dbo].[TablePDFTest] WHERE [name] = @name";

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlCode, Conn))
{
      //command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", nameE);

      using (reader = command.ExecuteReader())
      {
        // some action goes here...
      }
 }
```

How can I do the same with multiple parameters?

My code is this where I am using as a function padding the two parameters as a variable from another function:

```
public void writeData(string k, string c)
{
    Conn = new SqlConnection(cString);
    Conn.Open();

    //MessageBox.Show(k);
    //MessageBox.Show(c);

    var pdfPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/PDFTemplates/fw9.pdf"));

    // Get the form fields for this PDF and fill them in!
    var formFieldMap = PDFHelper.GetFormFieldNames(pdfPath);

    //if more than multiple entries, verify by name and the last four ssn
    //sqlCode = "SELECT * FROM [db].[dbo].[TablePDFTest] WHERE [name] = '" + k + "' AND [ssn3] = " + c + "";
    sqlCode = "SELECT * FROM [db].[dbo].[TablePDFTest] WHERE [name] = @name2 AND [ssn3] = @ssnnum";
    //MessageBox.Show("" + sqlCode.ToString());

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlCode, Conn))
    {
        //command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("name2", k);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ssnnum", c);

        using (reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
                    /*formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_01_0_[0]"] = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                    formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_02_0_[0]"] = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                    formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_04_0_[0]"] = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
                    formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_05_0_[0]"] = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
                    formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_07_0_[0]"] = reader.GetValue(4).ToString();
                    formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].social[0].TextField1[0]"] = reader.GetValue(5).ToString();
                    formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].social[0].TextField2[0]"] = reader.GetValue(6).ToString();
                    formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].social[0].TextField2[1]"] = reader.GetValue(7).ToString();
                    formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].social[0].TextField2[2]"] = reader.GetValue(8).ToString();
                    formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].social[0].TextField2[3]"] = reader.GetValue(9).ToString();*/
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Requester's name and address (hard-coded)
    //formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_06_0_[0]"] = "Medical Group\n27 West Ave\nPurchase, NY 10577";

    //var pdfContents = PDFHelper.GeneratePDF(pdfPath, formFieldMap);

    //PDFHelper.ReturnPDF(pdfContents, "Completed-W9.pdf");
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `Parameters` is a collection you can add more than one parameter to it.

Comment: + in mysql like that i have never seeen such i always saw and see infact . for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add parammeter as you did before.
This is how your code will loke like:

```
sqlCode = "SELECT * FROM [db].[dbo].[TablePDFTest] WHERE [name] = @name AND [ssn3] =@ssn3";

using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlCode, Conn))
{
      //command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nameE);
      command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ssn3", c);

      using (reader = command.ExecuteReader())
      {
        // some action goes here...
      }
 }
```

Comment: `command.CommandType = CommandType.Text` should be commented out?

Comment: My query is coming out empty :/

Comment: This question is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23956070/why-using-two-variable-causes-my-query-to-return-with-no-row

Comment: Ya you can comment it because command object usage 'CommandType' it's default value as 'CommandType.Text'

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge try running the query directly and make sure the values you enter match results

Comment: I ran the query in SQL and it works fine. Now I am passing the `@name` and `@ssn3` as variable within a function. Will that cause an issue?

Comment: I suspect you are getting no rows because of a type mismatch issue, just like in the cited question above.  I recommend using SQL query analyzer to determine the correct target query, fixing any issues with data types and formatting, then implementing that query in code as above.  The above code looks correct given the DB schema and data are "typical".  My guess there is something atypical about the data or schema.

Comment: Please post your T-SQL query that returns expected results.

Comment: I posted the entire C# function that I am using right now. Hope it helps.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge add tables schema and data sample , please

Comment: Updated my question with the schema and sample. Btw what if the data type changes?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge the only difference I see, is that before you was using variable c as number (no ' ' in string concatenation). look at parameters recived.

Comment: When I hover over the old code and inside the parameters command, it displays `(parameter) string c` so I am not sure why it's not working :/

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge where the data sample is from, a view? what values are you using when calling the function? what values return from SQL alone and what retrieves c# code?

Comment: The data sample is from my sql server. The function send it in as a string but the query itself worked without the `''` so I am thinking that's where the issue is?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge what values have you tried? are those string 4 character lenght?

Comment: In SQL mgmnt studio I tried any of the one displayed above and it worked fine. and it is always 4 character length.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge I just edited de answer, I forgot @!!! `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nameE);`
      `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ssn3", c);`

Comment: ha ha ha, but as you can see from my question, the first C# code also has the `@` missing but it's working fine. Hmmmmmm

Comment: Nope now when I press the button... nothing happens :/