# Updating Date Field in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, ms-access, sql-update

I'm trying to update a date (MM/DD/YYYY) using SQL in a C# program that uses an Access Database. The field only has a date and no time. However, I keep getting a Syntax error when I test the SQL in Access and a Microsoft Access Database Engine error when I try it in my program. Here is what I have tried:

Without #s

```
UPDATE [DELIVERY DATA BASE] SET DATE=03/03/2015 WHERE ID=12345;
```

With #s

```
UPDATE [DELIVERY DATA BASE] SET DATE=#03/03/2015# WHERE ID=12345;
```

How can I fix this?

I might also run into the same issue with time for another field, so if you have any insight into updating time using SQL, I'd appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: Any reason you don't just use parameterized SQL?

Comment: The cause of the syntax error is the word Date. You need square brackets around it because is a reserved keyword in Access. Said that and looking at your past questions I really suggest to stop coding for a while and study the Parameterized Query argument as suggested

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23956917/how-to-use-multiple-parameters-in-a-sql-queries/23957013#23957013

Comment: This part of my program is an edit window. The SQL statement is built in the edit window and around the parts of the record that are being edited. For example, if the date is the only thing being updated, the SQL only edits the date rather than the entire entry. Once the SQL is constructed, the statement is fed into another method that does the execution of the SQL. Since the execution method is in another class and since I haven't imported any database classes into the edit window, I don't use the parameterized SQL.

Comment: Wait, I think I just figured out what was going on. I was using the wrong Connection String. Thanks, everyone!